# Parse PushError 141 invalid function cloud code

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to get parse push notifications to work using cloud code. 
Here is what I have done:

In my AppDelegate.swift

```
        let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.current()
        currentInstallation?["user"] = PFUser.current()!.username!
```

Then I call the following cloud code function when a users username is mentioned

```
        // Create the push notification messages
        let pushMessage = "\(PFUser.current()!.username!) has mentioned you in a post."

        // Submit the push notification.
        PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "mentions", withParameters: ["message" : pushMessage, "User" : "\(word)"])
```

Here is my Cloud code

```js
  Parse.Cloud.define("mentions", function(request,result){
 
  var message = request.params.message;
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo("user",request.params.User); 
 
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data : { 
      alert: message,
      badge: "Increment",
    }
    }, {
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    response.success(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    response.error(error.message)
    }
  useMasterKey: true

  });

});
```

I then get error 141 when checking the logs

Answer (score 2):

I found two errors in my code first

1. it should have been

func(request, response)

2. it should have been

   response.error(error.message)
   }, // WITH A COMMA HERE
   useMasterKey: true